# Postgres on OS X can't find postgis extension control file

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Using mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.1.  I uninstalled and re-installed both postgres and postgis with homebrew.  I understand that postgres is looking in the wrong place for the postgis control file.  Also noticed that 'which psql' path seems incorrect.  How/where do I fix this?

psql

```
(9.4.0, server 9.3.5)

ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

find /usr -name postgis.control

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control
```

which psql

```
/usr/local/bin/psql
```

which pg_config

```
/usr/local/bin/pg_config
```

brew info postgis

```
postgis: stable 2.1.5, HEAD
http://postgis.net
/usr/local/Cellar/postgis/2.1.5 (45 files, 8.6M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/postgis.rb
```

brew info postgres

```
postgresql: stable 9.4.0 (bottled)
http://www.postgresql.org/
Conflicts with: postgres-xc
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0 (3049 files, 74M) *
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/postgresql.rb
```

Both .bashrc and .bash_profile have

```
export PGDATA='/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/bin/postgres'
alias postgres-log='cd /usr/local/var/postgres/ && subl server.log'
```

mdfind -name "postgres" | grep -G "postgres$"

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/bin/postgres
/usr/local/var/postgres
/Users/lionelramos/macports/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/ruby/rb-postgres
```

Looks like I have different a local version of postgres in addition to the homebrew version.

Answer (score 6):

How I solved my problem:

1. I uninstalled postgres 9.3.5_1 with `brew uninstall postgres 9.3.5_1`.
2. I uninstalled postgis with `brew uninstall postgis`
3. Made sure that I only had postgres 9.4 installed with `brew info postgres`
4. Made sure that `psql` command worked.
5. I reinstalled postgis with `brew install postgis`.

This solved my problem.  If you're having trouble with step 4 you might need to use initdb or createdb commands to create database needed.

Comment: That's pretty much the solution: Install the extension for the version of Postgres you're using. :)